# Wait wait wait wait... 1=0?

Tags: mathematics, word, english

*Wasn't quite sure if this was suitable for Puzzling; however it has a problem/puzzle in it, so decided to give it a shot. Please appropriately downvote if you feel you should.*

Yesterday morning I came to class as usual, and a student came up to me. He said he had a proof that could revolutionize mathematics.

Being a Grade 11 teacher, I didn't believe him.

So I asked him to tell me about the proof, he said *"I've divided it into several steps, and said it seemed to work perfectly well, with zero problems."* Then he told me *"It's a proof that 1 is equal to 0."*

So I asked if he could find any mistakes, he responded *"None that I could find, sir, however it wouldn't surprise me if there was. I had thought of it after you taught us factoring. I think you'd like to take a look".*

I indeed did, and he showed me, mentioning *that it was indeed stating $1=0$.*

Obviously this is false, and by looking at the paper I noticed his trivial error almost immediately.

> Assume x and y are two nonzero numbers.
>   $x = y$  
>   $x^2 = x*y $ 
>   $x^2 - y^2 = x*y - y^2  $
>   $x + y = y  $
>   $2*y = y  $
>   $2 = 1  $
>   $1 = 0$

However, I have a challenge for you, and this is to find the error my student made.

But not only that, you must explain how everything he told me was true.

Comment: Similar question [here.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/obi-wan-vs-grievous)

Comment: Not a duplicate. There's an additional word problem about"0 problems"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The errors lies here:

> There is an implicit division by 0 between steps 3 and 4. Step 3 states: $x^2-y^2=xy-y^2$. Factoring this produces $(x+y)(x-y)=y(x-y)$. Going to step 4 requires that you divide through by $(x-y)$, but step 1 implies that $x-y=0$.

He is *technically* correct in what he said because:

> He said the proof has "zero problems". This is correct; there is a problem with the number 0 in his proof.

Comment: Good job :) Did you think this puzzle was appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

The student divided by zero between the third and fourth lines. He wrote the third line as:

$(x + y)(x-y) = y(x-y)$

And proceeded to cancel the term $(x-y)$. This can be done if and only if $(x-y) \neq 0$, but since the hypothesis is $x=y$ we arrive at a contradiction.